# Problem of surface level values after using shading interp in Matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation, matlab-figure, ode

I am new to writing codes. Tried to create a colormap for the solution of ODEs system.
When executing, I keep getting zero values for Z-axis(surface level), but the data set of it exhibit non-zero values. Does it has to do with interpolation of "shading interp"? How can I fix it so that the values of the data set will appear?

```
%Preamble
clc
clear all
clear workspace
%Parameters:
A=21;
B=9;
C=0.17;
D=0.5*10^(-5);
E=11*10^(-7); %
F=0.045;
G=10^5;
H=9;
I=10^9;
M=100;
tspan =[0,2/24];
n_weeks =6;
Initial=[ 0 8*10^7 7*10^6 ];
y0 = Initial;
opt = odeset('AbsTol',1e-9,'RelTol',1e-6);
m1=6;
A=21.05;
%All the different initial conditions
tspan1 = linspace(0,365,100); %time of simulation
%Parameters that vary:
A = 21.05*linspace(0.5,2,11);
M =  100*linspace(0.5,2,11);
%Initial condition 1
for ii = 1:length(A)
for kk = 1:length(M)
odefcn =  @(t,x)[ -A(ii)*x(1)+m1;
-x(2)*C*x(1)/(x(1)+M(kk))+F*x(2)*(1-x(2)/I)-x(2)*(D*x(3)); 
B*(C*x(2)*x(1)/(x(1)+M(kk)))+x(3)*(-H)+G-E*x(3)*x(2)];
[t,x(:,:,ii,kk)] = ode45(odefcn, tspan1, y0, opt);

    end

end

%Data Extraction:
%This informs us how long our data set is
StoreInside = x(:,:);
%Loop length
Len = length(StoreInside(1,:))/3;
%Adding the first and second phase numbers together
for ii = 1:Len
T_1(:,ii) = StoreInside(:,2+3*(ii-1));
%Skips to next group
end
%Specific times - Halfway point
for ii = 1:Len
T1(:,ii) = T_1(length(t),ii);
end
x_contour = M';
y_contour = A';
[Y,X] = meshgrid(y_contour,x_contour);
%Collects data  - each entry is the different kmax values for a given

Z1=zeros(length(M),length(A));
for i=1:length(M)
Z1(i,:)=T1(:,(1+(i-1)*length(M)):(i*length(M)));  
end
%Z1 = [T1(:,1:11);T1(:,12:22);T1(:,23:33);T1(:,34:44);...
% T1(:,45:55);T1(:,56:66);T1(:,67:77);T1(:,78:88);...
%  T1(:,89:99);T1(:,100:110);T1(:,111:121)];

fig=figure(1);
pcolor(Y,X,Z1); %G1D1
hold on;
shading interp;
cb1 = colorbar;
cb1.LineWidth = 1.5;
ax1=gca;
set(gca,'YScale','log')
xlabel('A'), ylabel('M');
%xticks(0.5:0.1:1);
get(gca,'fontname');  % shows you what you are using.
set(gca,'linewidth', 2,'fontsize',24,'fontname','Helectiva'); % Sets the width of the axis lines, font size, font
set(gca,'TickDir','out');
set(gca,'YScale','log');
h = axes(fig,'visible','off');
bottom = min(min(min(Z1)));
top  = max(max(max(Z1)));
clim(ax1,[bottom, top]);                   % Set the same limit to first subplot
cb1.Position = [0 0 0 0];                   % Reduce the position for cb1
cb2.Position = [0 0 0 0];                   % Reduce the position for cb2
c = colorbar(h,'Position',[0.92 0.23 0.022 0.7]);  % attach colorbar to h
c.LineWidth = 1.5;
c.FontSize = 18;
c.Label.String = 'Cell Count';
clim(cb1.Limits);                          % Set the new colorbar limits
```

Comment: Did you try use surf() instead of pcolor() ?

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: But it makes it a 3D plot. Is it still possible to get 2D map?

Comment: But you talked about wanting a "z-axis suface level"... which to me implies that you want a 3D surface plot? Otherwise, what should your z-values represent?

Comment: Try imagesc() instead.